# $K$-free lattice on two generators where $K=\{$two element lattice$\}$

Tags: lattice-orders, universal-algebra

This is an example from [*A Course in Universal Algebra*][1]. Sorry, I can't copy all necessary definitions here; there are a lot of them.

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a type of algebras and $K$ be a class of algebras of type $\mathscr{F}$. $\mathbf{T}(X)$ denotes the term algebra of type $\mathscr{F}$ over $X$. $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ denotes the $K$-free algebra of type $\mathscr{F}$ over $\overline{X}$.

> In general $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ is not isomorphic to a member of $K$ (for example, let $K=\{\mathbf{L}\}$ where $\mathbf{L}$ is a two-element lattice; then $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{x}, \overline{y})\not\in I(K)$). However $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ can be embedded  in a product of members of $K$.

Page 68. I suppose that it means that $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ is not isomorphic for any set $X$. $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ was defined by
$$\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X}) = \mathbf{T}(X)/\theta_K(X),$$
$$\theta_K(X) = \bigcap\Phi_K(X),$$
$$\Phi_K(X) = \{\phi\in\operatorname{Con}\mathbf{T}(X) : \mathbf{T}(X)/\phi\in IS(K)\}.$$

Let $X=\{0, 1\}$. An obvious member of $\Phi_K(X)$ is $\ker\nu$ where $\nu$ is the homomorphism given by the universal mapping property of $\mathbf{T}(X)$ (Theorem 10.8). If it was the only member of $\Phi_K(X)$, then $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbf{L}$. I can't come up with another member that will make $\theta_K(X)$ smaller. That member $\phi$ must induce exactly 2 equivalence classes. If more, $\mathbf{T}(X)/\phi\in IS(K)$ would not hold.

Update. Can I choose $\phi$ in the following way? $\phi$ induces 2 equivalence classes, let's call them Class 0 and Class 1, such that Class 0 consists of variables, and Class 1 of all other terms. (In my case, there are exactly 2 variables: Variable 0 and Variable 1.) As the meet and join of $\mathbf{T}(X)$ produce a term that is not a variable, $\phi$ is a congruence.

Update 2 2018-03-17 11:05:23+00:00. With such $\phi$, $\mathbf{T}(X)/\phi$ would not be isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathbf{L}$, so $\phi\not\in\Phi_K(X)$. I still do not understand what is $\theta_K(X)$ and what can $\phi$ be.

[1]: Burris, Stanley, and H.P. Sankappanavar. *A Course in Universal Algebra.*  2012 ed. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1981. Web. *Stan's Home Page.* Graduate Texts in Mathematics 78. 10 Mar. 2018. <https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf >

Comment: Well since you have no assumptions on $K$, it's really easy to come up with a counterexample : pick for instance $K$ to be the class of all groups except for the free ones. Another example where it's easier to check is : $K$ is the class of finitely generated abelian groups, and $X$ is some infinite set. Then $F_K(X)$ is the free abelian group on $X$, and is thus not in $K$

Comment: I am asking about the two-element lattice.

Comment: @Max: I suspect that "$K$-free algebra" is not the same as "free algebra".

Comment: I'm so sorry I read too quickly and only answered what I thought the title meant

Comment: Your update doesn't work because if $x \theta y$ then $x \wedge y \theta x \vee y$.

Comment: @amrsa: Sorry, I do not understand. What is $x$, $y$, $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta$ is any congruence, or in the case you were trying, $\phi$. What happens is that, in lattices, if two elements are related by some congruence, then their meet is also related with their join by that congruence, so you can't have variables in one class and other terms in the other, since all terms are made from variables, meet and join.

Comment: @amrsa Oh, I see now. $\phi$ is a congruence for the term algebra $\mathbf{T}(X)$ which is not a lattice.

Answer (score 2):

The free lattice on a two element set is the four element lattice that is not a chain, that is, $\{x\wedge y,x,y,x\vee y\}$, with $x$ and $y$ incomparable.
Let us call $\mathbf M_2$ to this lattice.

To see this, let $f:\{x,y\}\to L$, where $\mathbf L$ is the two element lattice (the only member of $K$).
Then $\varphi:\mathbf M_2 \to \mathbf L$, defined by 
$$x \wedge y \mapsto f(x) \wedge f(y), \quad x \mapsto f(x), \quad y \mapsto f(y), \quad x \vee y \mapsto f(x) \vee f(y),$$
is a homomorphism (trivially), and it extends $f$, so $\mathbf M_2$ has the Universal Mapping Property for $K$ over $\{x,y\}$, and thus it is the free lattice in $K$ over $\{x,y\}$.

Clearly, $\mathbf M_2 \notin K$.

Comment: By "free lattice in $K$ over $\{x,y\}$", do you mean "$K$-free algebra over $\{x,y\}$"?

Comment: @beroal Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for describing $\mathbf{F}_K(\overline{X})$.